# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'views'

Tags: python, django

I am getting a nontype object error in my views
I was adding views functionality to my blog but when I use slugify in my tempate it throws nontype object error
My models looks like this

```
class Post(models.Model):
sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
author=models.CharField(max_length=14)
slug=models.CharField(max_length=130)
views= models.IntegerField(default=0)
timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
content=models.TextField()
```

and views looks like

```
def blogPost(request, slug):
  post=Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
  allPosts= Post.objects.all()
  post.views= post.views +1
  post.save()

  comments= BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post, parent=None)
  replies= BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post).exclude(parent=None)
  replyDict={}
  for reply in replies:
      if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
         replyDict[reply.parent.sno]=[reply]
      else:
          replyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)

context={'post':post, 'comments': comments, 'allPosts': allPosts, 'user': request.user, 'replyDict': replyDict}
return render(request, "blog/blogPost.html", context)
```

and I am getting this error

```
AttributeError at /blog/cyber-security
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'views'
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/cyber-security
 Django Version:    3.1.4
 Exception Type:    AttributeError
 Exception Value:   
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'views'
 Exception Location:    D:\www\allinfo\blog\views.py, line 21, in blogPost
 Python Executable: D:\www\venv\Scripts\python.exe
 Python Version:    3.9.0
```

Please help me out

Comment: `post=Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()` here `.first()` returns either the first object or `None` if none matches the query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def blogPost(request, slug):
  post=Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
  allPosts= Post.objects.all()
  post.views= post.views +1
  post.save()

  comments= BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post, parent=None)
  replies= BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post).exclude(parent=None)
  replyDict={}
  for reply in replies:
      if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
         replyDict[reply.parent.sno]=[reply]
      else:
          replyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)

context={'post':post, 'comments': comments, 'allPosts': allPosts, 'user': request.user, 'replyDict': replyDict}
return render(request, "blog/blogPost.html", context)
```

In this code, are you sure in your database there is some values is available, If database is empty or after filtering the database, there might be the case where there is no value in there, If you didn't handle it properly then you will get again with this query and it crashes the app, So, it is good if you will handle the exception using try: except: and redirect it if it didn't find the value it is looking for.